# Error "File too small" When using spm_slice_vol, Fieldtrip MATLAB

Tags: brain, neuroimaging, software, matlab

When I was trying to convert a CT scan file's coordinate system into an approximation of the ACPC coordinate system on Fieldtrip MATLAB, there was error prompting that:
`Error using spm_slice_vol, File too small.`

By the way, the `.nii` file of the CT scan seems to be incomplete in the anterior part of the brain.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend asking at the FieldTrip discussion list if you think there's an issue with FieldTrip, but if you have a data file that's missing data there's no way FieldTrip or anything else but the original source can replace it.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the information.